# How are SMB credentials negotiated?

Tags: samba

I have  a local USB drive mounted into a Linux box on my home network. I have samba installed and it shares a directory of that USB drive and I can connect to that share from my Windows box with the user/pass I have set up with smbpasswd for that user. That all works.

My concern is how those credentials are passed on the wire from my Windows box to my Linux box. I have captured the SMB transactions with Wireshark and I do not detect my credentials in any of the packets, but I do not have enough knowledge of the SMB protocol to dissect exactly where the authentication takes place.

Can someone explain to me how the credentials are passed in this scenario and whether I should expect to see them on the wire?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis is the [CIFS/SMB protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx)

Unless you're using Kerberos, the mechanism may still be [NTLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx):

1. A user accesses a client computer
   and provides a domain name, user name, and password. The client
   computes a cryptographic hash of the password and discards the
   actual password.
2. The client sends the user name to the server (in
   plaintext).
3. The server generates a 16-byte random number, called a
   challenge or nonce, and sends it to the client.
4. The client encrypts
   this challenge with the hash of the user's password and returns the
   result to the server. This is called the response.

etc.